# Character, element, or hack to push everything after it to the next page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a program that automatically populates a word document. Let's say the word document has 3 sections: A, B, and C. My program populates section B.  Section B can be 1 line or 100 lines, so what I want to be able to do is make section C automatically start on a fresh page.

```
section B
<newPageHack> <-- Can I add anything here to force section C onto a new page no matter how large section B is?
section C (on a new page)
```

Comment: what is your program?

Answer (score 0):

It makes a difference how this program populates your document, and how the program is written (language). Without that information all I can give is a rather generic answer.

An ASCII `Form Feed` character inserted into Word will generate a page break. The code is `12`. This can be entered with the ["Alt Code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) `012`. How you enter characters depends on your program, e.g. C++ `'12'`, VB `chr(12)`, etc.

Comment: I'm using C#/.net 3.5

Comment: Uhh.. I have no idea how you'd generate a Word document in C#, but C# character literals are more or less the same as C++.. inserting `char NewPage = '12';` might do it. [Oh, hey, look what I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/43d4ab18-cceb-47fd-a225-7930496f5acc/): `.InsertBreak(ref Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);`